# Standard Deviation (SD) vs. Coefficient of Variation (CV)

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation, coefficient-of-variation

Which of the following two data sets is more dispersed? Assume that both data sets are normally distributed.

Data Set A: $\mu_A = 1$, $\sigma_A = 1$.

Data Set B: $\mu_B = 10$, $\sigma_B = 1$.

Answer 1: Data Set A because $CV_A = \dfrac{\sigma_A}{\mu_A} = \dfrac{1}{1} = 1 > 0.1 = \dfrac{1}{10} = \dfrac{\sigma_B}{\mu_B} = CV_B$.

Answer 2: They are equally dispersed since the graph of Data Set B is exactly the same graph as Data Set A shifted $\mu_B-\mu_A=10-1=9$ units to the right.

How do we reconcile these two equally convincing answers?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: It is a good example of using a ambiguous word (dispersed) to smear the very clear and good defined statistical concepts (mean and standard deviation).

Comment: @StephanKolassa, not really. I'm just reading about these topics and this question popped to mind.

Comment: They're not equally convincing...

Answer (score 10):

Standard deviation and coefficient of variation are both measures of dispersion of a distribution, but which one is more useful will depend on context. SD is widely applicable, but there are situations where you definitely should not use CV.

Some measurements are taken on an *interval scale*, meaning that there's no true, non-arbitrary zero point on the scale - you can really only compare differences in measurements. Temperature, for example, could be on an interval scale, since 0 degrees F and 0 degrees C are both equally valid, and the zero point has no special meaning (although measuring temperature in Kelvin has a non-arbitrary zero and therefore isn't an interval measure). For anything measured on an interval scale, coefficient of variation is rather meaningless, since you could shift the scale to any numerical value arbitrarily and get an entirely new CV - there's no reason why you should prefer a CV measured in Fahrenheit rather than Celsius, suggesting that it's not a useful measure. CV should only be used for *ratio scales* for things like mass or length that have a non-arbitrary zero point.

If the data is on a ratio scale, CV and SD are both acceptable, but must be interpreted differently. In your example, both A and B have identical SD, indicating their variation is the same in an absolute sense. The difference in means results in different CVs, however, so dataset A has greater dispersion in a relative sense, in that the distribution varies more widely as a percentage of the mean.

Comment: Nuclear Wang, thank you for the enlightening answer! My understanding: Even if the data sets are on a ratio scale, there is still no clear-cut answer as to which is more dispersed. Relative sense: Data Set A is more dispersed. Absolute sense: Both data sets are equally dispersed. Did I understand it correctly?

Answer (score 5):

Nuclear Hoagie's answer brings up a good point, but there are several possibilities. For example, if one has temperature readings in Fahrenheit and Celsius, and we wish to apply proportional temperature laws to them, we can, but we have to use absolute temperatures.

For example, to apply P$\,$V$ = n \,$R$\,$T, [the ideal gas law](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/thermodynamics/temp-kinetic-theory-ideal-gas-law/a/what-is-the-ideal-gas-law), where ‍P is the pressure of the gas, ‍V is the volume taken up by the gas, ‍R is the Kelvin gas constant‍: R$_{\text{°K}}=8.31 \frac{\text{J}}{\text{°K}\cdot \text{mol}}$,
$n$ is the number of moles if the gas, and finally T is the absolute temperature of the gas in °K (degrees Kelvin), where °C$\, +\, 273.15 = \,$°K converts degrees Celsius to degrees Kelvin.

In the case where the temperature is in Fahrenheit degrees, we modify the ideal gas law and we convert to absolute temperature in degrees Rankine (°R), i.e., we calculate °R$\, = \,$°F$\, + \,459.67$, and convert the gas constant $\frac{5}{9}$R$_{\text{°K}} \to\,$R$_{\text{°R}}\approx \,4.62\frac{\text{J}}{\text{°R}\cdot \text{mol}}$, as a °K is $\frac{9}{5}\,$°R.

Next, there are circumstances in which we wish to compare different absolute measures on a relative scale. In which case there is another calculation called [Coefficient of Variation of the mean](https://influentialpoints.com/Training/coefficient_of_variation_of_a_mean.htm) that may prove useful. I suppose this could also be called Coefficient of Variation of the Standard Error of the mean. This pertains to measurements like mean or median values that cannot be negative, like mean versus median residence times of a drug in the body. And, for example, we might ask what the certainty of the mean value of a simulation is. The formula for this is CV$_{\text{mean}}=\,$CV/mean$\,=\dfrac{s}{\bar{y}\cdot\sqrt{n}}\;\;.$

There are circumstances when residence time measurements are very different.
Let's say we have a distribution of geometric mean times (GMD), as well as harmonic mean times (HMD), mean times (MD) and median times (MeD). These could be very different, for example

```
Mean
GMD: 31.905 HMD: 3.5398 MD: 73.190  MeD: 41.754
```

These values would not help us choose the more precise measurement because the scales are very different. Standard deviation wouldn't help, and standard error of the mean wouldn't help. Coefficient of variation would help in the sense of telling us how variable the measurements are on a relative scale

```
CV
GMD: 0.072548   HMD: 0.55294    MD: 0.056348    MeD: 0.086284
```

In this case we can see that the least variable measurements are the arithmetic mean values; MD. Finally, if we want to know how stable the values of the means are for each simulation method we can calculate the CV of means.

```
CV of means
GMD: 0.0032444  HMD: 0.024728   MD: 0.0025199   MeD: 0.0038588
```

This tells us what the error is of our calculating each distribution's CV. Since the CV values were obtained by Monte Carlo simulation, this tells us what the error of our CV simulation is for each measurement type. In this case, 500 simulations were used to estimate each CV and thus how good of a measurement the CV is, is $1/\sqrt{500}$ of each CV. The interpretation of that is that we have performed enough simulations to be able to distinguish significantly between different location values, i.e., geometric, harmonic, arithmetic, and median.

Even if these measures of location exist for a particular density function (or pdf), the formulas for them may not be known or even knowable in closed form, but if the measures of location exist and are not knowable, they can be found by discrete simulation as random variates using inverse methods. For the particular simulations shown, the density function was $f(t)=\frac{6 \,\beta}{\pi^2} \, \ln \left(\frac{1}{e^{\beta \, t}-1}+1\right)$, with $\beta=0.01$. For that function, the mean value is known, the median can be calculated directly from the density function, but the harmonic mean and geometric mean cannot be written in general form, at least not easily.

**EDIT:** The pdf used in the example above is not completely unknown as it has been used to model drugs eliminated by renal filtration. Simplifying, it can be written as $f(t)=-\frac{6 \,\beta}{\pi^2} \, \ln \left(e^{-\beta \, t}-1\right)$ is called the negative logarithm of cumulative exponential (LCE) distribution and was published [here](https://www.informahealthcare.com/doi/full/10.1080/00365513.2023.2275278) with a downloadable arXiv preprint [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.14995).